# Unable to enable Kafka feature on Azure Event Hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am trying to enable the Kafka feature on my Event Hub as described in the following link

https://www.codit.eu/blog/getting-familiar-with-azure-event-hubs-for-apache-kafka/?country_sel=uk

However, as you can see from my image of my Event Hub Namespace, I'm not provided with the option to Enable Kafka.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8RDL.png)

I read a past SO post where the answer was "As of now, “enable Kafka” feature is available on newly created Event Hubs." Also, the feature was only available in certain regions.

However, as you can see from my image, my Event Hub is within a region where Kafka is available and its newly created.

Therefore, can someone let me know why I can't see the Kafka feature in order to enable it?

However, as you can see from the image

Comment: [When you create a standard tier Event Hubs namespace, the Kafka endpoint for the namespace is automatically enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quickstart-kafka-enabled-event-hubs)

Comment: I went ahead and created the Event Hub namespace, but I don't see anywhere where Kafka endpoint is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Kafka endpoint` for the `Event hub namespace` is automatically enabled, so there is no such option during creation.

**Note that** `Event Hubs for Kafka` is available only on `standard` and `dedicated` tiers. The `basic` tier doesn't support Kafka on Event Hubs(see the `Note` section in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quickstart-kafka-enabled-event-hubs#create-an-event-hubs-namespace)). But in the image you provided, I see you are creating a `Basic tier` eventhub namespace. Please try to create a `Standard tier` eventhub namespace, like below:

[image]

After the `Standard tier` eventhub namespace is created, you can check Kafka is enabled as stated in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I created a Standard Tier as you suggested and I am able to see the Kafka enabled service

Comment: The answer only mentioned about the standard and dedicated tiers but Premium tier also support the Kafka feature